# Extract information from Google's inspect element

Tags: image, element, extract, inspect

I would like to access information from google's inspect element. In particular, the image sizes.

I use beautiful soup to scrape a site given a source, however, is there any way I can access image information from google's inspect element and where I would start?

Comment: Inspect Element is the place where you start and it shows the CSS information where you can get the details like height and width of the img. from. Is your question about finding something else?

Comment: @Prash i guess what I'm trying to say is if there's a way to access this information through writing a code. Or if I'm entirely off track

Comment: Not really sure why you need to depend on Google's inspect element. You can always make an ajax call to url to get the complete HTML chunk of the page (url) and from there you can always parse the response of that request. After all, the complete request is the response of a html page... so you should be able to parse it through a DOM parser or load it into some javascript XML Parser.